# Ограничение области видимости мелких функций

Tags: c++, namespace

Допустим, надо как-то выделить какой-то небольшой код, чтобы вызывать его во многих местах пары функций.
Собственно для себя нашел пару вариантов - шаблон в отдельном пространстве имен или старый добрый сишный макрос.

Интересует, что думают об этих вариантах профессиональные программисты и, возможно, ещё что-то посоветуют?

```
// вариант №1 отдельное пространство имен, где собирается весь утилитарный хлам
namespace makemove { 
    template <class T>
        inline void SWAP(T & a, T & b) noexcept {
            T t = a;
            a = b;
            b = t;
        }
}

void board15::makemove(const directions & dir) {
    using namespace makemove;
//#define SWAP(a,b) {int t = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = t;} // вариант № 2
    switch (dir) {
        case UP:
            // там внутри не самые короткие выражения, нет смысла их приводить
            SWAP(board[/* ... */], board[/* ... */]); 
            current_pos_y += 1;
            break;

        case DOWN:
            SWAP(board[/* ... */], board[/* ... */]);
            current_pos_y -= 1;
            break;

        case LEFT:
            SWAP(board[/* ... */], board[/* ... */]);
            current_pos_x += 1;
            break;

        case RIGHT:
            SWAP(board[/* ... */], board[/* ... */]);
            current_pos_x -= 1;
            break;
    }
//#undef SWAP
    return;
}
```

P.S. в std::swap из "utility" тыкать не надо, это к вопросу не относится.

Comment: Я так понимаю, использование макросов все здесь считают строго неприемлемым?

Comment: Не строго неприемлемым, конечно. Но если макросов можно избежать, их стоит избегать. В C++ есть более адекватные средства. Задайте отдельный вопрос, почему macros are evil, получите интересную информацию к размышлению.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам где-нибудь нужна мелкая функция, чтобы не засорять область видимости, можно положить её в анонимное пространство имён:

```
namespace
{
    template <class T>
    inline void SWAP(T & a, T & b) noexcept {
        T t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }
}
```

Таким образом функция будет видна только в том файле, где определена, и не будет вызывать конфликтов компоновщика, если в соседнем файле объявлена такая же. Эта техника имеет смысл при использовании в .cpp-файлах, при использовании в header'ах вы, наоборот, получаете много копий одинакового кода.

Answer (score 1):

Я - не профессиональный программист, так как я - всего лишь безработный, но тем не менее выскажу свое мнение.:)

Если эта общая часть кода дублируется в нескольких функциях - членах класса `board15`, то я выделил бы его в отдельную приватную функцию этого же класса. Функция может быть либо статической, либо не статической в зависимости от того, нужно ли ей иметь дело с другими нестатическими членами класса помимо тех, которые можно ей передать в виде аргументов.

Например,

```
class board15
{
private:
    static void swap( Board &board1, Board &board2 )
    {
        // можно ее определить внутри класса, чтобы сделать ее встраиваемой
        // либо просто добавить спецификатор функции inline в ее объявление
        // если это целесообразно. 
    }
//...
};
```

То есть если эта функция входит в реализацию вашего класса и не является обобщенной для нескольких классов или объектов, то ее следует сделать членом  вашего классе.

Это не мешает ей быть к тому же шаблонной функцией.

Что касается данного подхода

```
namespace makemove { 
    template <class T>
        inline void SWAP(T & a, T & b) noexcept {
            T t = a;
            a = b;
            b = t;
        }
}

void board15::makemove(const directions & dir) {
    using namespace makemove;
//...
```

То я бы его сходу забраковал. Непонятно, почему классы, которые используют функцию и сама функция объявлены в различных пространствах имен, если эта функция связана с объектами только этих классов. И вместо  using директивы я  рекомендовал бы по крайней мере использовать using объявление данной функции.

Answer (score 1):

Можно пометить функцию ключевым словом static, чтобы она была видна только в текущем файле. Ну и естественно, её не надо включать в заголовочный файл с прототипами.